# Trigger to Update a Parent Record based on a value in a child record

Tags: apex, before-trigger, childrecords

I need to update the Order record when it's status changes to Activated.  I want to set the custom field, `invoice_Due_date__c` based on a related record's value.  The related record is child record in the object `Payment_Terms__c` and there will only ever be 1 record related and a field `number_of_days__c` populated.

Ultimately when the order is activated I want to set the field, `invoice_due_date__c` to the `activateddate + number_of_days__c` from the child record.

I am really stuck with this, I couldn't see how to manage it in the process so i assume the best way is to run an beforeupdate trigger on the order object.  I have some experience with basic triggers and came up with the following but I know I am going wrong somewhere.  Any advice would be appreciated:

Thanks,

The following sits in my OrderActions class which is called by a trigger handler/trigger via the beforeUpdate context just now.  It brings up a cannot de-reference null object error.  I've tried a few varitaions but also understand a for inside a for is poor design.

```
public static void OrderAddInvoiceDueDate(List<Order> Order){
        Set<Id> idSet= new Set<Id>(); //set of Id's
        //popupate the set with the Order ID's
        for (Order o : (List<Order>) Order){            
            idSet.add(o.Id);
        }
        List<Payment_Terms__c> pt = new List<Payment_Terms__c>([SELECT id, number_of_days__c, order__c FROM Payment_Terms__c WHERE order__c IN :idSet]);
        for (order orlist: order){
            if (orlist.status == 'Activated'){
                for (Payment_Terms__c ptexists: pt){
                    if (ptexists.order__c == orlist.id){
                        Date newDate = date.newInstance(orlist.activatedDate.year(), orlist.activatedDate.month(), orlist.activatedDate.day());
                        orlist.Invoice_Due_Date__c = newDate.addDays(ptexists.number_of_days__c.intValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you instead have a field say `number_of_days_on_payment__c` on `Order` object which always is the current value of `number_of_days__c` from `Payment_Terms__c`. And whenever an `Order` is updated, just use this value from `Order` instead of going to find out from the child.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to approach this scenario, I would have done it the following way (considering there's always a 1:1 relationship between your objects).

1. Create a custom field say `number_of_days_on_payment_terms__c` field on `Order`. If you can have the relationship between `Order` and `Payment_Terms__c` as a Master-Detail relationship, you can just create `number_of_days_on_payment_terms__c` as roll up summary field. In that case, you don't even need step 2.
2. If only you cannot have a Master-Detail relationship between your object, then this step is applicable. Every time the field `number_of_days__c` changes on `Payment_Terms__c` record, just copy it over on `Order`. This can be achieved either through trigger or workflow rule. This ensures that the field on `Order` is always updated with the value from `Payment_Terms__c`.
3. Now, whenever the `Order` is set to `Activated`, write the trigger on `Order` and just use the value on `number_of_days_on_payment_terms__c` on `Order` to calculate the `invoice_Due_date__c` field.

With this approach you eliminate the complexity of going into child records and finding out the values, etc. and that you get the value as required right on the record you are operating on.